Usage of festlegen and entscheiden
In this paragraph two verbs have been used with more or less same meaning. The verbs are festlegen and entscheiden, so what's the contextual difference?

Ich lege gemeinsam mit meiner Trainerin fest, wie intensiv ich trainieren muss. Und ich muss mich natürlich oft entscheiden.


The words can be used as synonyms and are used in a fitting way here.
"Entscheiden" is perhaps the simpler one to explain: it means "to decide" or "to make a decision": one has two (or more) alternatives and takes one of them. Notice that the verb from which "entscheiden" is derived is "scheiden", which means "to part" or "to separate".

Und ich muss mich natürlich oft entscheiden.

From the context you gave (training) the decision is to continue working (hard) or to stop/work less hard. I'd interpret the sentence as: a voice in me says "stop working and relax" and I have to overcome that voice constantly.
"Festlegen" has to do with decisions and making them but only indirectly: "fest" here is used in the sense of "rigid" or "fixed": things are flexible and could take any direction but one decides for a certain direction and then the one course of actions is fixed and - rigidly - going in the direction decided upon. So, "festlegen" is not so much about a decision process but about the decision itself and how that influences destiny.
One decides upon the intensity of the training and, depending on the decision, training would take a different course, but after the "Festlegung" (the noun derived from "festlegen") it is one and only one course of actions.

In addition to bakunin's answer: While both verbs often translate as "to decide", entscheiden is about the process of decision-making whereas festlegen is more about the outcome (that something now has been decided). Depending on context, festlegen may also translate to to fix, to determine, or to schedule (when it's about a point in time something is supposed to happen).

I don't see much of an intersection. Entscheiden is choosing between alternatives and festlegen is some sort of commitment. Of course you can do that at the same time, but the commitment can also follow the decision by a significant time span.
(I have some problems with the example sentence, since I don't see an obvious object to the decisions apparently required.)
So you may decide to travel to Greece in your vacation, but the commitment is only done, when you sign the booking with the travel agency, rent the car etc.
When you decide to quit smoking, this decision may be easily revoked as long you don't commit by telling to some other people.

"Entscheiden" is taking decisions on variable (but mutually exclusive) ways to act. The standard use is in court rules where various alternatives of considering right or wrong are dissected. "Das Gericht entschied .." means "the court decided that... "
In companies the CEO's "entscheiden" (take decisions) about the major guidelines for future products or developments.
"Festlegen" is used in normaliztion efforts of rules in industry/technology in all cases where common standards make sense. "Die DIN norm legt fest, dass die Schrauben folgende Durchmesser haben." (The DIN specifies that the screws ought to have the following standard lengths.) In particular for calendar fixes of dates we have "festlegen" as means to agree on common times or places for meetings, and in software "festlegen" agrees on protocols and interface issues like connectors and wires.
